# How to export default 2 constructors?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

I try to run the React JS file where you can see below

```
const PostArticles = ({classes, ...props})

const Categories = ({classes, ...props})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(withStyles(styles)(PostArticles));

export default connect(mapStateToPropsCat, mapActionToPropsCat)(withStyles(styles)(Categories));
```

I want to export these 2 constructors to be print data from mongodb by using react js but I get this error

SyntaxError: C:\Users\hatzi\Desktop\restapi-client\src\components\PostArticles.js: Only one default export allowed per module. (197:0)

Can you help me please?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I know but the code was very big to copy paste it

Comment: Please cut it down to a [mre], then.

Comment: Better? I need this help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error clearly states that you cannot have more than one default export.

Instead, you can use a named export.

For example:

```
const PostArticles = ({classes, ...props})

const Categories = ({classes, ...props})

export const PostArticlesConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(withStyles(styles)(PostArticles));

export const CategoriesConnected = connect(mapStateToPropsCat, mapActionToPropsCat)(withStyles(styles)(Categories));
```

Please also look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

If you indeed want to use default exports - you should split those 2 connected components into different modules.

Comment: I tried it and then I get this:


./src/App.js
Attempted import error: './components/PostArticles' does not contain a default export (imported as 'PostArticles').

Comment: @AlexandrosChatziandreou so as soon as you use named export - you should use named import as well (like `import {PostArticlesConnected} from './components/PostArticles'`)